# referrer ip manipulation

Tags: security, request, httprequest, referrer

Some applications are providing security only by accepting requests from certain IPs. Is this a good way of making that app secure. Is there any way to manipulate this referrer IP during request period?

getRemoteAddr, getRemoteHost and getRemotePort

Is there any way to set the values above when making the request?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I'm trying to consider the APIs you mention and figure out what you mean by 'referer' here; the methods you mention relate to the remote end of the connection, which is different than the HTTP referer header field.  Which one do you mean?

Comment: sorry for that. i am talking about the remote end of the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to "spoof" the source IP of packets to make the request appear to be from a different IP address than it really is.  However, this is not a concern because the three-way handshake of TCP will not complete if the IP address has been spoofed, with a few exceptions (such as the attacker sniffing packets and generating a response when the packet passes on the wire).  Generally speaking though, it is very hard to do.

This is not good security practice, however, even though it is typically reliable.  The reason is that IP addresses can be assumed by anyone, and they are frequently changed in packets due to techniques like NAT and fire-walling.

Consider that if you have two users on the same private network using NAT, and they both make requests to your server at the same time, your server will see the IP addresses as the same, with different source ports.  The differentiating factor that allows routing to happen properly is the source *port*, not the IP address.  To make this even less reliable, the source port will change on every new request, which can happen dozens of times during a single HTTP session.

That being said, there is some benefit to IP filtering.  You can make it much harder for someone from a certain country or area to connect by filtering by IP.  This should not be your *only* security, but it can help because it is usually non-trivial to obtain a valid IP address from a a different range.  Some organizations will block all non-US based IPs by default, for example.  This is used in conjunction with user accounts.  This makes it much more difficult for non-local attackers to reach the server.

Comment: Thanks very much for this great explanation. So if i have the information of which ip/port's are allowed i can easily create packets and send these packets and i can bypass this ip filtering assuming that the protocol is http. am i right? what if it is https? I think if the protocol is https this way of security is still a good way.

Comment: Yes, if you know which IP/Ports are allowed you could create and send those packets, bypassing the IP filtering.  If it is https it would not work unless you somehow had the crypto key (such as with a man-in-the-middle attack)